# Get height value in real time whilst CSS transition is in progress

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am creating a progress bar where its percentage value will be set when the page is loaded from the server, via a data attribute. I do not expect this value to change once the page has loaded. For the purposes of this post, I have entered a static value inside `data-prog-percentage`.

The intention is for the label above the progress bar to update as the bar increases, alongside the 2s CSS transition. This is for visual effect only, however I cannot seem to get the value updating in real time. Even once the transition is complete, the value does not update from its original (0%). If I run the code in the Chrome dev tools console, the value updates.

I tried a while loop, however this just froze the browser tab.

How can I update the value of the label in real time alongside the transition? Or is this not possible?

The code I have is as follows:

```js
var percentageTarget = $(".prog-bar .bar").data("prog-percentage");
$(".prog-bar .bar .prog-inner").css('height', percentageTarget + '%');

//Update percentage label
var percentage = Math.round($(".prog-bar .bar .prog-inner").height() /
  $(".prog-bar .bar .prog-inner").parent().height() * 100);

$(".prog-bar .percentage-text").text(percentage + '%');
```

```css
.prog-bar h4 {
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.prog-bar h5 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.prog-bar .bar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 220px;
  margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0px 6px rgba(162, 162, 162, 0.26);
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.prog-bar .bar .prog-inner:before {
  content: ' ';
}

.prog-bar .bar .prog-inner {
  height: 0%;
  background-color: #8D5B4C;
  transition: height 1.5s ease-out 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="prog-bar text-center">
  <h4 class="percentage-text">0%</h4>
  <h5>Complete</h5>
  <div class="bar row align-items-end" data-prog-percentage="67">
    <div class="col prog-inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to bind observers with events start ,progress and end, then it will be just a callback to show the percentage filling with bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen for [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event)  and [transitionstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionstart_event) :

On transitionstart a timer can start and terminate on transitionend.

```js
var percentageTarget = $(".prog-bar .bar").data("prog-percentage");
$(".prog-bar .bar .prog-inner").css('height', percentageTarget + '%');

//Update percentage label
var percentage = Math.round($(".prog-bar .bar .prog-inner").height() /
        $(".prog-bar .bar .prog-inner").parent().height() * 100);

$(".prog-bar .percentage-text").text(percentage + '%');




var clearTimer = null;
$('.prog-inner').on('transitionstart', function(e) {
    clearTimer = setInterval(function() {
        var percentage = Math.round($(".prog-bar .bar .prog-inner").height() /
                $(".prog-bar .bar .prog-inner").parent().height() * 100);

        $(".prog-bar .percentage-text").text(percentage + '%');
    }, 50);
})
$('.prog-inner').on('transitionend', function(e) {
    clearInterval(clearTimer);
})
```

```css
.prog-bar h4 {
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.prog-bar h5 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.prog-bar .bar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 220px;
  margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0px 6px rgba(162, 162, 162, 0.26);
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.prog-bar .bar .prog-inner:before {
  content: ' ';
}

.prog-bar .bar .prog-inner {
  height: 0%;
  background-color: #8D5B4C;
  transition: height 1.5s ease-out 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="prog-bar text-center">
    <h4 class="percentage-text">0%</h4>
    <h5>Complete</h5>
    <div class="bar row align-items-end" data-prog-percentage="67">
        <div class="col prog-inner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks! I knew I had to use some kind of event handler but I wasn't sure how, plus I need to now do some reading up on intervals! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you explain why you added popper.js to the scripts, please? Is this required?

Comment: see [installation guide](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/#js). In any case, you are right, in this case it is not required. But I prefer to add always the libs like described in the doc